# how to disable gcc warning "cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]"

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, gcc-warning

I am new to cmake and gcc.
The first assignment in my new role in the company was to clean the errors from our linux compilation
I did most of it, and now the only warning I see is

`cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]`

I want wither to suppress the warning or to solve the issue in the cmake file.
Unfortunately, I still haven't found the correct `-Wno-xxx` statement that fits here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code issue warnings can be silenced with `-Wno-xxx` options because sometimes you don't have control over the source code. But a warning telling you that a *command-line option* is incorrect cannot be silenced with yet another command-line option — if you can affect compiler invocation, then why not just remove the incorrect option?

This particular warning tells you that you cannot set standard to C++11 when compiling C code. To get rid of it, find where `-std=c++11` is defined in the build configuration, and make sure it is only applied to C++ compilation, and not for C. For example, move it from `CFLAGS` to `CXXFLAGS`, or cmake's equivalent thereof.

Comment: I am able to get rid of this comment if I disable the warning "Warn if '0' is used as a null pointer constant[-Wzero-as-null-pointer-const]. Not sure how it is related

Comment: @JonWheelock This question is about the warning produced when using the `-std=c++11` when compiling C. According to [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), `-Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-const` is a C++ option, and is as not even recognized by gcc compiling C files.